# Node js mysql works syncronous (strange behaviour)

Tags: mysql, node.js, asynchronous

Ok, need some help.

Have an application on node js and mysql. I'm not exactly understand behaviour of connections.

Here is my code (part of it).

```
let connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    database: "mans",
    user: 'root',
    password: '',
}).promise();

let results = [
    // array of objects
];

await Promise.all(
    results.map(r=>{
        return connection.query("UPDATE `table` SET `name` = ?, WHERE `id` = ?", [r.name, r.id]).then(r=>{
            console.log('end iteration');
        }).catch(err=>{
            console.log('err: ', err);
        });
    })
)
```

Now, when `map` function start (ofcourse aync as excpected), then `query` works as simple sync function! Well, maybe it is because im not using pools. So i rewrite it.

```
let pool = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit: 100,
    host: "localhost",
    database: "mans",
    user: 'root',
    password: '',
}).promise();

let results = [
    // array of objects
];

await Promise.all(
    results.map(r=>{
        return pool.getConnection().then(connection=>{
            console.log('opened connection');
            return connection.query("UPDATE `table` SET `name` = ?, WHERE `id` = ?", [r.name, r.id]).then(r=>{
                connection.release();
                console.log('end iteration');
                return;
            }).catch(err=>{
                console.log('err: ', err);
            });
        }).catch(err=>{
            console.log('err: ', err);
        });
    })
)
```

Open connection event fired async and successfully, but update still wait each other. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Ok, some update. Tried to use `START TRANSACTION` and `COMMIT` commands. And on my local Windows server it works, all operations gone async. Without it it was syncronous. But it did not worked on server with Ubuntu 18.04 and mysql 5.7. Operations was still synced. Update after update. Checked engine, it was `InnoDB`

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i have got some result. But it does not any sense for me. If anyone can clarify this, please do it.

My problem solved with add `INDEX` to `ID` field (was without it) in `WHERE` statement. With `START TRANSACTION` and `COMMIT` features it started to work asynced.

Again, without it or without index on id, update worked synced - only when previous one end.

Comment: It might not be changing to async, but now the update is so fast that you can't tell the difference.

Comment: Ok, you are right. I did another benchmark and yes, it was fast but still one after another. But then, my question is still open, why its not work async as i want?